# Success on emulator, Force stop on real device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, emulation

I deployed an application for Android which is successfully running on emulator.
But, when I try to run on real device (My device is Acer A200, tablet), my application always forced stop. The requirement of the operating system is no problem.

The error in logcat when I tried to run on real device is :

```
07-16 15:09:20.870: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(780): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: kategori, db=/data/data/com.mroring.belajarperancis/databases/MY_DATABASE
```

I think the application didn't install the database correctly. What should I do ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: check is that table is there are not.

Comment: in your code check if the table exists and if not create a new table and use it...

Comment: my handheld has not been rooted yet :(

Answer (score 0):

table name "kategori" does not exist on your database, you should check the code if you created the table or not. if created, change the version number of the database, It will call the onUpgrade method and the database will create again.